# Logging compatibly with logrotate

Tags: c, linux, logrotate

I am writing a Linux daemon that writes a log. I'd like the log to be rotated by logrotate. The program is written in C.

Normally, my program would open the log file when it starts, then write entries as needed and then, finally, close the log file on exit.

What do I need to do differently in order to support log rotation using logrotate? As far as I have understood, my program should be able to reopen the log file each time logrotate has finished it's work. The sources that I googled didn't, however, specify what reopening the log file exactly means. Do I need to do something about the old file and can I just create another file with the same name? I'd prefer quite specific instructions, like some simple sample code.

I also understood that there should be a way to tell my program when it is time to do the reopening. My program already has a D-Bus interface and I thought of using that for those notifications.

Note: I don't need instructions on how to configure logrotate. This question is only about how to make my own software compatible with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally, my program would open the log file when it starts, then
>   write entries as needed and then, finally, close the log file on exit.
>
> What do I need to do differently in order to support log rotation
>   using logrotate?

No, your program should work as if it doesn't know anything about logrotate.

> Do I need to do something about the old file and can I just create another file with the same name?

No. There should be only one log file to be opened and be written. Logrotate will check that file and if it becomes too large, it does copy/save the old part, and truncate the current log file. Therefore, your program should work completely transparent - it doesn't need to know anything about logrotate.

Comment: Note that that this needs the "copytruncate" configuration for logrotate - is the fallback solution to be used if the logging program cannot be told to re-open it's log file. The program have to have opened the log file in append mode for it to work - and it can lose log messages. A better way is to have logrotate interact with the program (e.g. send it a unix signal, or use other program specifics) to have the program close and re-open the log file when it is rotated.

Answer (score 10):

There are several common ways:

1. you use `logrotate` and your program should be able to catch a signal (usually SIGHUP) as a request to close and reopen its log file. Then `logrotate` sends the signal in a postrotate script
2. you use `logrotate` and your program is not aware of it, but can be restarted. Then `logrotate` restarts your program in a postrotate script. Cons: if the start of the program is expensive, this may be suboptimal
3. you use `logrotate` and your program is not aware of it, but you pass the copytruncate option to `logrotate`. Then `logrotate` copies the file and then truncates it. Cons: in race conditions you can lose messages. From `rotatelog.conf` manpage

   > ... Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost...
4. you use `rotatelogs`, an utility for httpd Apache. Instead of writing directly to a file, you programs pipes its logs to `rotatelogs`. Then `rotatelogs` manages the different log files. Cons: your program should be able to log to a pipe or you will need to install a named fifo.

But beware, for critical logs, it may be interesting to close the files after each message, because it ensures that everything has reached the disk in case of an application crash.

Comment: Re: "But beware, for critical logs, it may be interesting to close the files after each message, because it ensures that everything has reached the disk in case of an application crash". This is terrible advice. Closing the file has nothing to do with making sure the data is on disk.

Comment: @navin: you are right on one point: closing the file brings the data half the way to the disk because it is only guaranteed not to be in userland buffers nor in any file level system buffer. Of course, the filesystem could still buffer it. That means that you are immune to a program crash, but not to physical disk crash nor a system panic. But honestly, being immune to a program crash is often the only requirement...

Comment: 'being immune to a program crash is often the only requirement' ->  closing the log file after each log message is still terrible advice under this requirement. Why not simply call `fflush()` when you are using stdio then? Or even write each message directly with `write()`? Btw, buffering isn't the only issue you have to deal with when writing critical logs - IO operations (including close) might fail due to IO errors, as well.

Answer (score 7):

Although `man logrotate` examples use the HUP signal, I recommend using `USR1` or `USR2`, as it is common to use HUP for "reload configuration". So, in logrotate configuration file, you'd have for example

```
/var/log/yourapp/log {
    rotate 7
    weekly
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -USR1 yourapp
    endscript
}
```

The tricky bit is to handle the case where the signal arrives in the middle of logging. The fact that none of the locking primitives (other than `sem_post()`, which does not help here) are [async-signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) makes it an interesting issue.

The easiest way to do it is to use a dedicated thread, waiting in [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html), with the signal blocked in all threads. At exit time, the process sends the signal itself, and joins the dedicated thread. For example,

```
#define  ROTATE_SIGNAL  SIGUSR1

static pthread_t        log_thread;
static pthread_mutex_t  log_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static char            *log_path = NULL;
static FILE *volatile   log_file = NULL;

int log(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list  args;
    int      retval;

    if (!format)
        return -1;
    if (!*format)
        return 0;

    va_start(args, format);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&log_lock);
    if (!log_file)
        return -1;
    retval = vfprintf(log_file, format, args);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_lock);
    va_end(args);

    return retval;
}

void *log_sighandler(void *unused)
{
    siginfo_t info;
    sigset_t  sigs;
    int       signum;

    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, ROTATE_SIGNAL);

    while (1) {

        signum = sigwaitinfo(&sigs, &info);
        if (signum != ROTATE_SIGNAL)
            continue;

        /* Sent by this process itself, for exiting? */
        if (info.si_pid == getpid())
            break;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&log_lock);
        if (log_file) {
            fflush(log_file);
            fclose(log_file);
            log_file = NULL;
        }
        if (log_path) {
            log_file = fopen(log_path, "a");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_lock);
    }

    /* Close time. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&log_lock);
    if (log_file) {
        fflush(log_file);
        fclose(log_file);
        log_file = NULL;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_lock);

    return NULL;
}

/* Initialize logging to the specified path.
   Returns 0 if successful, errno otherwise. */
int log_init(const char *path)
{
    sigset_t          sigs;
    pthread_attr_t    attrs;
    int               retval;

    /* Block the rotate signal in all threads. */
    sigemptyset(&sigs);
    sigaddset(&sigs, ROTATE_SIGNAL);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, NULL);

    /* Open the log file. Since this is in the main thread,
       before the rotate signal thread, no need to use log_lock. */
    if (log_file) {
        /* You're using this wrong. */
        fflush(log_file);
        fclose(log_file);
    }
    log_file = fopen(path, "a");
    if (!log_file)
        return errno;

    log_path = strdup(path);

    /* Create a thread to handle the rotate signal, with a tiny stack. */
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(65536);
    retval = pthread_create(&log_thread, &attrs, log_sighandler, NULL);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);
    if (retval)
        return errno = retval;

    return 0;       
}

void log_done(void)
{
    pthread_kill(log_thread, ROTATE_SIGNAL);
    pthread_join(log_thread, NULL);
    free(log_path);
    log_path = NULL;
}
```

The idea is that in `main()`, before logging or creating any other threads, you call `log_init(path-to-log-file)`, noting that a copy of the log file path is saved. It sets up the signal mask (inherited by any threads you might create), and creates the helper thread.  Before exiting, you call `log_done()`.  To log something to the log file, use `log()` like you would use `printf()`.

I'd personally also add a timestamp before the `vfprintf()` line, automatically:

```
    struct timespec  ts;
    struct tm        tm;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == 0 &&
        localtime_r(&(ts.tv_sec), &tm) == &tm)
        fprintf(log_file, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03ld: ",
                          tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday,
                          tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,
                          ts.tv_nsec / 1000000L);
```

This `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss` format has the nice benefit that it is close to a worldwide standard ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) and sorts in the correct order.